# Benchmark by number of iterations per constant interval

Tags: ruby, benchmarking

For benchmarking the efficiency of different algorithms for a simple task and comparing them, the way I find most often is to set a constant number of times to iterate over the task, and measure the time interval spent for each algorithm.

But, if the number of times is set too small, the interval difference among the algorithms will be too small, and may be masked by external factors. If you set the number of times too large, then it will take too much time to execute. So you have to guess the right number of times by trial end error.

Rather than doing it this way, I think it makes more sense to set a constant time interval that you want to run each algorithm, and then measure how many iterations can be made in that interval for each algorithm.

By doing so, the reliability of the benchmark will be more stable. In the conventional way, the benchmark will be more reliable for tasks that take time.

I haven't seen this way of benchmarking. Do people actually do this way, and is there a benchmarking framework for this way of measurement? I am asking this as a non-language-specific question, but if there is such framework, especially for Ruby, please introduce some. Or am I wrong about this idea?

Comment: I've seen it done that way, but it's really just a spin on how we do it with Ruby's built-in `Benchmark`. If you're using too small an interval for a test you could get a partial run of a complex routine and have to iteratively increment the value until you finally get something meaningful, so basically it's six of one, half dozen of the other.

Comment: @theTinMan For the fixed interval, I have in mind at least a few seconds, or maybe tens of seconds, and by "simple task" that I mentioned in the question, I meant simple enough to be able to run for a meaningful number of times within that interval.

Comment: It still remains a variation on what we do now. Instead of specifying the number of loops, we'd specify the number of seconds to loop and count the number of iterations. There'd still be times we'd fidget with the values to get a meaningful difference. Spurious events on the system could still effect the tests, so multiple tests would still be needed to reduce their effect.

Comment: One advantage is that, the reliability of the benchmark is proportional to the interval that the test was run. And by fixing that, you can fix the reliability of the test. If you have the number of iterations as constant, then the reliability depends on how much time the task takes: the longer, the less obscured by external factors and more reliable. And I agree with you that this is not almighty. For more complicated tests, it cannot be applied.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. What is the benchmark supposed to do when the alotted time for one algorithm is over? Aborting the execution somehow is risky: it could leave open files or database connections or whatnot. Maybe keep the algorithm running to its end and subtract one from the number of succesful runs?

Comment: That is what I had in mind. The result will always be a natural number, and in rare cases will the results have adjacent numbers, so adding/subtracting one should not matter much.

Comment: You might want to glance at [Perl's Benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html). It offers both methods of testing.

Comment: Got it. `countit`. That looks great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at perfer:

https://github.com/jruby/perfer

This has a couple of mechanisms including iterations/s.  Don't worry that this is a jruby repo, it works on all Ruby implementations and was written as part of GSoC 2012.

Answer (score 2):

I found this gem: [benchmark/ips](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips).